# Avoid in-memory calculation for OneToMany ... when fetching MAX 1 Child

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using Spring Data JPA and have the entities that map to their respective tables. I need to query the results so that I can fetch all the parent and one child per parent based on their `strength`.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
  @Id
  Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
  @Id
  Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Strength strength;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
  private Parent parent;
} 

public Enum Strength {
  STRONG,
  NORMAL,
  WEAK
}
```

I have a basic crud repository as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface ParentRepository extends CrudRepository<Parent, Long>{}
```

Some rules and assumption:

1. A child belongs to a single parent
2. A parent can have many child objects in DB
3. A parent can have 0 or 1 child that has strength = STRONG
4. A parent will have 1 child that has strength = NORMAL
5. A parent will have 0 or more child objects that has strength = WEAK
6. A weak child is never returned
7. The `getParentAndStrongChildren` method below should return a max of 1 child.

I can do a `findAll` query on Parent Repository method in Spring and then map the results in memory something like this

```
public List<Parent> getParentAndStrongChildren(){
    List<Parent> parents = parentRepository
        .findAll().stream()
        .map(p -> {
            if(p.getChildren() != null && p.getChildren.size() > 1){
               Child found = p.getChildren().stream()
                            .filter(c -> c.getStrength() == Strength.STRONG)
                            .findFirst()
                            .orElseGet(()-> p.getChildren().stream()
                                             .filter(c -> c.getStrength() == Strength.NORMAL)
                                             .findFirst()   
                                             .orElse(null));
                p.setChildren(found == null ? null : new Arrays.asList(found));
            }
        }
    return parents;
}
```

**Q: Is there any way to not do the filters in memory and rely on JPQL and @Query annotation to achieve this?**

Comment: You have a lot of logic there, maybe only a native SQL can do this job for you. Can you do that logic on a SQL query? Will be easiest to us help you using a SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical "[top N per category](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/)" SQL query. I personally doubt this can be done with JPQL, but maybe someone else will provide an answer. Here's a standard SQL solution to your problem, using lateral:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT c.*
  FROM child c
  WHERE p.id = c.parent_id
  AND c.strength != 'WEAK'
  ORDER BY CASE c.strength WHEN 'STRONG' THEN 1 WHEN 'NORMAL' THEN 2 END
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) c ON 1 = 1
```

Alternatively, using window functions (also standard SQL):

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM parent p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT c.*, row_number() OVER (
    PARTITION BY c.parent_id 
    ORDER BY CASE c.strength WHEN 'STRONG' THEN 1 WHEN 'NORMAL' THEN 2 END
  ) AS rk
  FROM child c
  WHERE c.strength != 'WEAK'
) c ON p.id = c.parent_id AND c.rk = 1
```